# GridSearchCV: How to write the output of each configuration to a csv as it finishes and not altogether?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, hyperparameters

I am using scikit-learn's `GridSearchCV` to run a grid search over a variety of of hyperparameters. After `GridSearchCV` is complete I can write the output of the grid search to a csv by accessing `grid_search_object.cv_results_`.

However, instead, I want to write the output of each configuration as it finishes to a csv, not altogether. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A workaround is to set the `verbose` attribute of the GridsearchCV to 3 so that the candidate parameters and the score are logged and capture the output of the log into a file. You can do as follows:

```
from sklearn import svm, datasets
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
import sys

old_stdout = sys.stdout
log_file = open("cv.log","w")
sys.stdout = log_file

iris = datasets.load_iris()
parameters = {'kernel':('linear', 'rbf'), 'C':[1, 10]}
svc = svm.SVC()
clf = GridSearchCV(svc, parameters, verbose=3)
clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)

sys.stdout = old_stdout
log_file.close()
```

This will write the result as well as the parameters of each iteration into the file. You can see below an example of the `cv.log` content:

```
Fitting 5 folds for each of 4 candidates, totalling 20 fits
[CV 1/5] END ................C=1, kernel=linear;, score=0.967 total time=   0.0s
[CV 2/5] END ................C=1, kernel=linear;, score=1.000 total time=   0.0s
[CV 3/5] END ................C=1, kernel=linear;, score=0.967 total time=   0.0s
[CV 4/5] END ................C=1, kernel=linear;, score=0.967 total time=   0.0s
[CV 5/5] END ................C=1, kernel=linear;, score=1.000 total time=   0.0s
```

Comment: verbose doesn't work with `n_jobs != 1`